# How to sort values in object key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to sort only the values in keys "items" ?

```
function solve(input) {
    let heroes = {};

    for (const line of input) {
        let [name, level, items] = line.split(' / ');
        if(!heroes.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            heroes[name] = {
                level: Number(level),
                items: items
            }
        }
    }

    let inArrEntries = Object.entries(heroes)

    inArrEntries.sort((a, b) => (a[1].level - b[1].level))

    console.log(inArrEntries);
}
```

Output:

```
[
  [ 'Hes', { level: 1, items: 'Desolator, Sentinel, Antara' } ],
  [ 'Derek', { level: 12, items: 'BarrelVest, DestructionSword' } ],
  [ 'Isacc', { level: 25, items: 'Apple, GravityGun' } ]
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  [ 'Hes', { level: 1, items: 'Antara, Desolator, Sentinel,' } ],
  [ 'Derek', { level: 12, items: 'BarrelVest, DestructionSword' } ],
  [ 'Isacc', { level: 25, items: 'Apple, GravityGun' } ]
]
```

.............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I want to sort items alphabetical in every object

Comment: only the values, without sorting objects by items keys

Comment: Why is items a string instead of an array?

Comment: that was my task input

Comment: Where's your attempt at resolving this yourself?  The JS you posted doesn't seem to be related to your question, at all.

Comment: Your task input seems to be a plain text, but it is your code that makes objects with the string property still in CSV format. The idea is to make it an array.

Comment: please show expected result

Comment: You'll have to split items into its individual words (as an array), sort that, and rebuild the string. Better yet, your input could be text but that doesn't mean you have to store it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all the entries, [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) `items` on `", "`, [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it, and then [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on `", "`.

```js
const inArrEntries = [
  [ 'Hes', { level: 1, items: 'Desolator, Sentinel, Antara' } ],
  [ 'Derek', { level: 12, items: 'BarrelVest, DestructionSword' } ],
  [ 'Isacc', { level: 25, items: 'Apple, GravityGun' } ]
];
for(const entry of inArrEntries){
     entry[1].items = entry[1].items.split(", ").sort().join(", ");
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(inArrEntries));
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer! :)

Comment: @YoanIvanov No problem!

Answer (score 0):

Items should be an array instead of string. However, if you cannot modify this, you should take each array, get the second item which is an object, then take `object.items` string, split it into array, sort that array, join it, and then replace item property with given value.

Answer (score 0):

I simply done :

```js
const data = 
      [ [ 'Hes',   { level:  1, items: 'Desolator, Sentinel, Antara'} ] 
      , [ 'Derek', { level: 12, items: 'BarrelVest, DestructionSword'} ] 
      , [ 'Isacc', { level: 25, items: 'Apple, GravityGun'} ] 
      ] 

data.forEach(el=>
  {
  el[1].items = el[1].items.split(', ').sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)).join(', ')
  })

console.log( data )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```